# Passing a portable Class to an Activity with Xamarin's Mono for Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm developing an app with Xamarin which will be released on Windows Phone, iOS and Android. This project includes a fair amount of portable code which is used in all three versions.

Currently I'm working on the Android app and have run into an issue - I need to pass one of my portable classes (A simple model which holds a few primitive values) into an activity. This should be a simple case of implementing IParcelable, but because this is a portable class I can't simply extend Java.Lang.Object, so I'm not sure where this leaves me.

**How can I allow my model to be passed to an activity via a bundle without changing the portable class?**

A very simple example of what I'm talking about:

*The portable Model*

```
// This cannot be changed
class MyModel {
  public int Number { get; set; }
  public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

*The model implementing IParcelable*

```
// I have tried this, however IParcelable requires inheriting from Javal.Lang.Object
// This throws a notimplementedexception
class MyParcelableModel : MyModel, IParcelable {
  public int DescribeContents()
  {
    return 0;
  }

  public void WriteToParcel(Parcel dest, ParcelableWriteFlags flags)
  {
    dest.WriteInt(Number);
    dest.WriteString(Text);
  }
}
```

*Finally, this is how I would like to pass this model to the activity*

```
var intent = new Intent(Activity, typeof(MyActivity));
var bundle = new Bundle();

bundle.PutParcelable("model", model); // 'model' is an instance of MyParcelableModel
intent.PutExtras(bundle);
Activity.StartActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as the data you want to pass in your Intent will be minimal, you can keep your class as-is and use [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for the serialization.  For example:

```
string jsonModel = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myModel);
intent.PutExtra("model", jsonModel);
```

then in your other Activity, it would be something like:

```
string json = intent.getExtra("model");
Model model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(json);
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! My models are fairly small and simple so this is perfect, but for larger classes would this still perform well?

Comment: Json.NET performs very well, but the problem I'd worry more about is that Intents limit how much memory you can use for the extras.  I don't know what that is offhand though.  For larger dataset you'll want to retrieve the data from elsewhere after  the Activity is started.